# The gray levels don't remain the same with scipy.misc.imresize()

Tags: python, image, scipy

I have an image which I would like to resize (upscale).
I don't want extra gray levels to be introduced in my image. That's why I used the nearest neighbour interpolation as follows:

```
  scipy.misc.imresize(image, image2.shape, interp="nearest",mode="L")
```

Original gray levels in the image:

```
[ 0  2  4  5  8  9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 35 36 37 38 41 43 45 46 47 51]
```

After interpolation:

```
[  0  10  20  25  40  45  50  55  60  70  75  80  85  90  95 100 105 110
115 125 130 135 140 145 150 155 160 175 180 185 190 205 215 225 230 235
255]
```

I also tried changing the mode, but it didn't help.
I have no clue that how to fix it.

Comment: interestingly all the new values are multiple of , its really funny

Comment: Seems like it just rescaled your gray levels to fit the range 0..255. Can you provide a MRE? I cannot reproduce this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`imresize` uses PIL or Pillow to do the actual work.  It is the conversion to a PIL image with mode 'L' that triggers the rescaling of the data values.  If the input data type is not 8 bit, the values are scaled to fill the 8 bit range.

One way to avoid this is to ensure that the input array has data type `numpy.uint8`.  Then the values are not rescaled.

For example, here is a 3x4 image with 64 bit values (i.e. the data type of the array is `numpy.int64`):

```
In [132]: img
Out[132]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  2, 17],
       [ 4,  3,  1,  2],
       [ 1,  5,  4,  2]])
```

Here's what happens when this array is passed to `imresize` with `mode='L'`:

```
In [133]: imresize(img, (6, 8), interp='nearest', mode='L')
Out[133]: 
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,  16,  16, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,  16,  16, 255, 255],
       [ 48,  48,  32,  32,   0,   0,  16,  16],
       [ 48,  48,  32,  32,   0,   0,  16,  16],
       [  0,   0,  64,  64,  48,  48,  16,  16],
       [  0,   0,  64,  64,  48,  48,  16,  16]], dtype=uint8)
```

If instead the input is first cast to `np.uint8`, the values are not rescaled:

```
In [134]: imresize(img.astype(np.uint8), (6, 8), interp='nearest', mode='L')
Out[134]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2, 17, 17],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2, 17, 17],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  3,  1,  1,  2,  2],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  3,  1,  1,  2,  2],
       [ 1,  1,  5,  5,  4,  4,  2,  2],
       [ 1,  1,  5,  5,  4,  4,  2,  2]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: I see, I passed a `uint8` array to `imresize` in my tests, that's why I didn't see the rescaling.